# jquery accordion function to add and remove class, nothing happens

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a jquery accordion without using the query-ui accordion() function.

So I have a jquery function that is supposed to remove a class from each accordion section and then add the class to the section that was clicked on. I'm guessing that's the issue because it doesn't seem to be working at all. Any suggestions?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxerG/)

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordions").on("click", function() {
        $(".accordions").removeClass("out");
        $(this).addClass("out"):
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="info-box">
        <div class="accordions" id="accordions">
            <div class ="title">About Me</div>
            <div class="goodies">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordions" id="accordions">
            <div class ="title">Why Me?</div>
            <div class="goodies">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordions" id="accordions">
            <div class ="title">Hobbies</div>
            <div class="goodies">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordions" id="accordions">
            <div class ="title">Links</div>
            <div class="goodies">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.accordions {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    transition: height 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease;
}

.accordions:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

.out {
    height:auto;
    transition: height 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: height 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
    -o-transition: height 1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error as pointed out by the previous answer, but an improved solution can be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $accordions = $(".accordions");
    $(".accordions .title").on("click", function() {
        var $acc = $(this).closest('.accordions').toggleClass("out");
        $accordions.not($acc).removeClass("out");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kvGWA/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordions").on("click", function() {
        $(".accordions").removeClass("out");
        $(this).addClass("out"): // <-- Change this to a semi-colon
    });
});
```